# Immutable JS - How to replace a list with a new list

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I have a React + Redux app which uses Immutability.js. In my reducer I have state defined as an Immutable List

`const initialSuggestedResponseState = Immutable.List([]);`

Every time a specific action happens, I would like to replace this list with a new list. I think I am missing something with Immutability.js as I have not been able to figure out a working solution. So far I have tried things like this:

```
        state.clear();
        action.messages.forEach(message => {
            let newResponse = new suggestedResponseRecord({
                body: message.body,
                responseId: message.response_id,
                type: message.type
            });
            state.push(newResponse);
        });
        return state;
```

This however does not push *anything* to my list. Why does this not work, and what is the appropriate methodology? I'm sure there is something MUCH simpler.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing state.push on any sort of immutable object returns a new object. The existing state is not modified, which is why returning the state after pushing to it doesn't work. A quick hack would be to change `state.push(newResponse);` to `state = state.push(newResponse);`. I suggest you read up more on how immutable structures work :)

Comment: Ah! Yes that makes perfect sense. Thanks :)

Comment: This defeats the purpose of immutability.

Comment: Which is why I said it was a quick hack to make it work

Comment: Regardless, it shouldn't be accepted is my point. I have written an answer that keeps immutability

Comment: My answer solves the problem in the smallest amount of code change and lets the person asking the question go investigate how he should be using immutable properly while having working code.

Comment: it doesn't solve the problem as it defeats immutability and doesn't address the question that was asked. SO isn't for temporary fixes of code

Answer (score 1):

As a follow-up to zackify's answer, here's one approach you could take to simplifying your code:

```
return new List(action.messages.map(message => {
    return new suggestedResponseRecord({
        body: message.body,
        responseId: message.response_id,
        type: message.type
    });
});
```

This creates an array of records from your array of messages (using [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)), then converts that new array into an immutable list. Not sure if this is the most efficient way of doing things, but it's quite readable.